# Unable to determine the codec required

Tags: matlab, video, matlab-cvst

I am using 2013a version of matlab and windows xp.When i run the code of videoreader i get this error.So what type of codec needs to be installed.

```
obj.reader = vision.VideoFileReader('first.avi');
 obj.videoPlayer = vision.VideoPlayer();
 obj.maskPlayer = vision.VideoPlayer();
  obj.detector = vision.ForegroundDetector('NumGaussians', 3, 'NumTrainingFrames', 40, 'MinimumBackgroundRatio', 0.7);
  obj.blobAnalyser = vision.BlobAnalysis('BoundingBoxOutputPort', true,'AreaOutputPort', true, 'CentroidOutputPort', true,'MinimumBlobArea', 400);
```

Comment: There is no error displayed.  You only showed the code that you wrote.

Comment: Ya...But when i run in my system it shows Unable to determine the codec required..Should i download any codec for this??

Comment: MATLAB is complaining that the video you are trying to get MATLAB to read in has no compatible codec installed.  This usually means that the video file is corrupt and has nothing to do with the codec itself.  If you read the documentatoin for `vision.VideoFileReader`, AVI is compatible with all platforms: http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/ref/vision.videofilereader-class.html. Try converting your video to another format... like MPEG-4, then try it again.

Comment: Tried converting into mp4 format also.But that solution also failed.This video is not playing in windows media player but its gud going in vlc.

Comment: VLC has more powerful codec capabilities whereas MATLAB only has a subset of codecs.  I guess you're out of luck.

Comment: If the video is not playing in Windows Media Player, then there is a good chance that MATLAB will not be able to read it either.